# attic access to the outside

Tags: doors, attic

If i build in my attic 2 bedrooms do I need to have a access door to the outside or some kind of ladder. The attic is the 2nd story of my home and has normal stairs going up from the main floor living space.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to have a ladder for a second story window.  However I would buy one and keep it in a well known place.  They are literally $30 for a drop ladder.  I won't recommend any because I have never had to use one and don't want to recommend anything that is poor.

First any municipality will make you have formal stairs getting to the second level.

Second you need to understand these numbers (US) - you need a window that meets them:

- no more than 44" above floor (bottom of the window)
- 20" wide
- 24" high
- and 5.7 total square feet

Couple of notes here.

1. I have had inspectors check that the window is able to open and close.  So if you are thinking about buying a solid framed window, I would ask your inspector first.  I have never installed this on a second story of a home so I can't say I missed an inspection, but I have seen an inspector open a few windows to make sure they were in working order.
2. I have messed up the 5.7 total square feet.  I had a framed window of 24" high by 24" wide, so you would say - "meets code".  No, it wasn't because it didn't meet the 5.7 requirement.  Luckily inspector noticed this during rough-in (I had already bought window but still).  This is one of those mistakes you only make one time.

Comment: Just want to clarify that the window dimensions you list are for the **opening**, not the total size of the window or the size of the glass. For a double-hung or sliding window the opening is much smaller than the total window size.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on your use of the term second story, which means different things in different parts of the world.

If you have a ground floor (ground level access) a first floor (no ground level access) and a second floor it is normal and customary to provide two means of egress (dual staircases, a staircase and an external fire escape, etc.) from bedrooms on the "second" floor, which is the "third" floor in the system below.

If you have a first floor (ground level access) and a second floor (no ground level access) it is generally considered acceptable in most LAHJs to have one staircase as access to that second floor. There should, however, be windows of a size sufficient to be considered "egress windows" in all bedrooms (which are larger than you may anticipate, since they are meant to be able to permit a fire department person in full turnout gear and an air pack to get in, grab a person in need of rescue, and get out.)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have two forms of egress. Your stairs likely counts as one, as long as it's appropriately sized.  A properly sized window in each room could be your second.

Depending on your location, there may be requirements for ladders from any egress *x* ft. above final grade.